# Error while cloning source code of package (bzr: ERROR: Not a branch)

Tags: packaging, launchpad, bazaar

I'm following the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/udd-intro.html) (UDD) and was faced with an error when I had tried to clone an existing package on third step.

```
$ bzr branch ubuntu:kdetoys
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/ubuntu/kdetoys/".
```

What does it mean? Where did I make a mistake?

Version of bzr package is 2.7.0-2ubuntu3, version of bzr-builddeb package is 2.8.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The message means that repository does not exist, so the command gets unexpected reply from LP server.

  Either that repo was deleted, renamed or moved.
- If you want to stick to the same project, use:

  ```
  bzr branch lp:kdetoys
  ```

  from https://code.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/kdetoys/trunk

  but I'm not sure it will work as expected (without issues for a getting started)